# Why does every new deployment of a project on WildFly continue to work without replacing the previous version?

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jboss, wildfly

Applications are already running on the WildFly server (with the @Schedule annotation). I wanted to make my own application by copying the skeleton.

After several deployments of the project (using mvn clean install wildfly: deploy), I noticed that previous versions are not being replaced. That is, only one deployment is visible in the WildFly interface, but in fact all previous deployments are working.

I tried to fix it with the redeploy command, but it doesn't help. Only WildFly reboot helps, after which only the last deployment starts working.

For all other applications (written before me), the wildfly: deploy command works fine, replacing the previous version every time.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

UPD: After uninstalling the application through the WildFly interface, it still continues to work...

UPD: The project is written using EJB on WildFly 11.0.0.Final.

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/30", persistent = false)
public void jobChecker() {
    ...cut...
    timeInterval();
    ...cut...
}

private void timeInterval() {
        Runnable task = () -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    lastStartedJob = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    job();
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(intervalTimeout);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    logger.error("Time interval error. ", e);
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
    
        jobThread = new Thread(task, "JOB_5");
        jobThread.start();
    }

[org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) unRegistering EJB client context for classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.Appexpress.ear" from Service Module Loader
[org.wildfly.extension.batch] (MSC service thread 1-2) Removing batch environment; ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.Appexpress.ear.ModuleexpressProducer.jar" from Service Module Loader
[org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0010: Stopping weld service for deployment Appexpress.ear
[org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment Appexpress_24072019.ear (runtime-name: Appexpress.ear) in 1361ms
[org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "Appexpress_24072019.ear" (runtime-name: "Appexpress.ear")
[org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) added javax.persistence.api dependency to Appexpress.ear
[org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Creating module: deployment.Appexpress.ear
[org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Adding dependency ModuleDependency [identifier=javax.ejb.api, moduleLoader=local module loader @6fffcba5 (finder: local module finder @34340fab (roots: /opt/wildfly/modules,/opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base)), export=false, optional=false, importServices=true] to module deployment.Appexpress.ear
[org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Module deployment.Appexpress.ear defined by Service Module Loader
[org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Module deployment.Appexpress.ear.ModuleexpressProducer.jar defined by Service Module Loader
[org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'ServiceRunner' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "ModuleexpressProducer.jar" of deployment "Appexpress.ear"' are as follows:
```

Comment: How can you tell the "previous version are not replaced"? By default the `wildfly:deploy` goal will either deploy or replace a deployment if the runtime names are the same. Are you changing the version or artifact name in some way?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins No, I just call the command "mvn clean install wildfly:deploy".

Comment: How can you tell it's not being replaced then?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins The program starts according to the schedule, creates a new thread and prints about it in the log. I change the name of the thread every time and so I saw that the projects are not replaced.

Comment: The deployment should be getting replaced. However, you may still have a thread from the previous deployment running if you don't stop it before you undeploy it.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I seem to understand what happened. I set the schedule too low - Schedule(hour = "\*", minute = "\*", second = "*/30", persistent = false). Therefore are not replaced my projects? How do I replace deployments correctly?

Comment: The deployment should be getting replaced. How do you schedule threads?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I didn't understand your question. Therefore, I supplemented the topic with examples from the code. Can you ask your question in more detail?

Comment: I'm not an EJB expert so I could be wrong here, but you could try passing in a `Timer` and canceling it I think. It's possible there was a bug in WildFly 11 too as it's quite old now. A side note you should look at using the `ManagedExecutorService` instead of creating threads like that as well.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Why is another project with the same code and schedule replaced and stopped? My project was stopped via the Wildfly interface, but the logs show that multiple instances of the project are still running? Maybe I don’t know some trick when deploying? 
Can you provide a link on how to pass the Timer?

Comment: I added logs in a different project. You can see what is happening with this project. My project does not have such logs.

Comment: Something seems to not be stopping the scheduled EJB. I'm not sure why. I'd have to create some kind of project to see if I can reproduce it. The deployment seems to be getting redeployed fine. However there seems to be an issue with fully removing the previous app.